# Bubble(chat) box css3

Tags: html, css, chat

I am creating an chat box for my website. In which i am using css3 to create message design.
I am facing an problem in design with firefox, it works fine in chrome.

Here is the image --

**FireFox Browser :**

[image: This image is of firefox]

**Chrome Browser**

[image]

Ans my css

```
.chat 
 {
position: relative;
max-width: 240px;
padding: 3px;
background: #fff;
border: #D1D2D4 solid 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 7px;
margin-left: 15px;
float:left;
display: inline-block;
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: pre-wrap;
 }

.chat:after 
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
left: -7px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px 7px 5px 0;
border-color: transparent #fff;
display: block;
width: 0;
  }

.chat:before 
 {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
left: -12px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 8px 11px 8px 0;
border-color: transparent #D1D2D4;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
 }
```

I need chrome design which should be work in all major browser. Help me to create css for this design compatible for all browsers.

Comment: From [this tutorial](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/) I made [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Edt2d/2/)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `height:0` to the `:before`and`:after`

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Edt2d/1/)